# format @Query parameter - Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I switched to using Retrofit2 and everything is nice and clean...
But there is a service call that requires that a query parameter be inside a regular expression(don't ask me why, I already asked for it to be changed).

Here is how my method looks like:

```
@GET("prod/search")
fun searchProducts(@Query("q") q: String?): Call<Array<Product>>
```

If I call `searchProducts("lala")`, the query will look like: `prod/search?q=lala`, but I need it to look like `prod/search?q=(?i)\\Qlala\\E`

Is there a simple way to format the query parameter to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think, you can use only another method. Something like this:

```
    searchProducts(prepareParameter("lala"))

    fun prepareParameter(query: String) = "(?i)\\\\Q" + query + "\\\\E"
```

Also you can use Interceptor. But it would be call in every request, so I recommend you use first variant.

```
object : Interceptor {
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain?): Response {
                val original = chain!!.request()
                val originalUrl = original.url()
                if (originalUrl.encodedPath().contains("prod/search")) {
                    val value = originalUrl.queryParameter("q")
                    val newUrl = originalUrl.newBuilder()
                            .setQueryParameter("q", "(?i)\\\\Q$value\\\\E")
                            .build()

                    val request = original.newBuilder().url(newUrl).build()
                    return chain.proceed(request)
                }

                return chain.proceed(original) 
            }
        }
```

And in your retrofit builder:

```
val client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .addInteceptor(yourInterceptor)
                 .build()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().client(client).build()
```

Comment: That's my solution right now. I just wanted to know if there's a way i don't know about in the Retrofit lib. I'm new to Retrofit. Have been using a custom solution for REST Api calls until now.

Comment: @Mugur Update answer, you can also use inteceptor. But I think, it worse option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the statical typing for your advantage. From the `@Query` documentation:

> Values are converted to strings using `Retrofit.stringConverter(Type, Annotation[])` (or `Object.toString()`, if no matching string converter is installed) and then URL encoded.

You'd only have to create a simple wrapper of `String` and override `toString()`:

```
data class RegularString(val value: String) {
    override fun toString() = "(?i)\\\\Q$value\\\\E"
}
```

Then use `RegularString` as a query parameter:

```
@GET("prod/search")
fun searchProducts(@Query("q") q: RegularString): Call<Array<Product>>
```